# changing permission for files and folder recursively using shell command in mac

Tags: macos, shell, permissions

In Linux we can use the following command to change permission mode of the files and folders recursively.

> find "/Users/Test/Desktop/PATH" -exec
>   * chmod 777 {} \;

how could i do the same for mac as i m getting the following error repeatatively.

> find: TEST_FILE: No such file or
>   directory

Answer (score 54):

The issue is that the `*` is getting interpreted by your shell and is expanding to a file named `TEST_FILE` that happens to be in your current working directory, so you're telling `find` to execute the command named `TEST_FILE` which doesn't exist.  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with that `*`, you should just remove it.

Furthermore, you should use the idiom `-exec program '{}' \+` instead of `-exec program '{}' \;` so that `find` doesn't fork a new process for each file.  With `;`, a new process is forked for each file, whereas with `+`, it only forks one process and passes all of the files on a single command line, which for simple programs like `chmod` is much more efficient.

Lastly, `chmod` can do recursive changes on its own with the `-R` flag, so unless you need to search for specific files, just do this:

```
chmod -R 777 /Users/Test/Desktop/PATH
```

Answer (score 47):

You can just use the -R (recursive) flag.

```
chmod -R 777 /Users/Test/Desktop/PATH
```

Answer (score 18):

By using CHMOD yes:

For Recursive file:

```
chmod -R 777 foldername or pathname
```

For non recursive:

```
chmod 777 foldername or pathname
```

Comment: If mac complain about operation not permitted, execute with sudo

Answer (score 9):

I do not have a Mac OSx machine to test this on but in bash on Linux I use something like the following to chmod only directories:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \+
```

but this also does the same thing:

```
chmod 755 `find . -type d`
```

and so does this:

```
chmod 755 $(find . -type d)
```

The last two are using different forms of subcommands. The first is using backticks (older and depreciated) and the other the **$()** subcommand syntax.

So I think in your case that the following will do what you want.

```
chmod 777 $(find "/Users/Test/Desktop/PATH")
```

Comment: I think that's a better answer since in most cases files and directories won't have the same permissions. BUT I think the '.' reference is dangerous – if you're in the wrong directory you can easily mess things up. Also answers 2 and 3 don't work if the arguments list is too long.

Answer (score 1):

IF they Give Path Directory Error!

In MAC
     Then Go to Folder **Get Info** and **Open Storage and Permission** change to **privileges** *Read To Write*