# "Permission denied (publickey) lost connection" when using scp to copy files from local machine to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp, private-key, permission-denied

I am trying to copy a file from my local machine (MAC) to my ec2 instance.

I followed [Amazon's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html) and this is what my command looks like:

```
ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com  <-- Works

scp -i /path/my-key-pair.pem /path/SampleFile.txt ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~  <-- Error shown below
```

- The key I am using is the correct key I used to connect to the
  instance successfully.
- Permissions 400: `chmod 400 /path/my-key-pair.pem`
- ssh traffic is enabled on port 22

The full logs are:

```
The authenticity of host 'public dns.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com (public dns)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:w+...
ECDSA key fingerprint is MD5:..
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-public-dns.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

---

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host public-dns.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com, user ec2-user, command scp -v -t ~
Warning: Identity file /path/my-key-pair.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-public-dns.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com [public-dns] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-public-dns.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:w+2eNNYg99E8tXX0cWuz0RYbmovKMirlUTeay32KYd8
debug1: Host 'ec2-public-dns.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

---

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834526/changing-permission-for-files-and-folder-recursively-using-shell-command-in-mac), The file I am trying to copy over to my ec2 instance hould have all the necessary permissions after I use `chmod -R 777 Documents/[the file's location]`.

*How do I  transfer the public key to the server?*

I have been stuck on this for many hours, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: looks like the identity file `/path/my-key-pair.pem` is missing or inaccessible. are you passing `/path/my-key-pair.pem` as the `-i` argument?

Comment: @MunavirChavody, yes I am.

Comment: Try this, https://askubuntu.com/questions/311558/ssh-permission-denied-publickey